# TextServicesManager not working in sony tablet

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I'm working of a custom keyboard which needs to use default dictionary if installed in ICS , I have check on emulator its wokring fine , but now installed in sony tablet S , SpellCheckerSession always returns null.

```
final TextServicesManager tsm = (TextServicesManager) getSystemService(
                    Context.TEXT_SERVICES_MANAGER_SERVICE);

            SpellCheckerSession mScs;
            mScs = tsm.newSpellCheckerSession(null, null,new SpellCheckerSessionListener() {

                public void onGetSuggestions(final SuggestionsInfo[] arg0) {
                    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    for (int i = 0; i < arg0.length; ++i) {
                }                                       

                    Log.i("OnGetSuggestion","Suggestion Returned :: "+sb.toString());
                }
            }, true);
```